# React update List item state as performant as possible

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently creating an React Application with an Editable Details list. My Issue is that I am not managing to update the list in a fast way. Specially Internet Explorer is struggling allot.

It would be to much to use my Application as example so I created a simplified concept in codesandbox: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-sanderson-of08y

For this Example I am just Rendering a lot of `<input/>` and let the parent container handle the state.

```
function App() {
   console.log('Render App')

   const [items, setItems] = useState(createItems())

   const handleChange = (value, index) => {
       const itemsCopy = [...items]
       itemsCopy[index] = value
       setItems(itemsCopy)
   }

   const handleSave = () => {
       //Send data to back-end etc...
       //webAPI.saveData(items)
   }

   return (
       <div>
           <button onClick={handleSave}>Save</button>
           <hr />
           {items.map((item, index) => {
               return (
                   <input
                       key={index}
                       value={item}
                       onChange={e => handleChange(e.target.value, index)}
                    />
             )
           })}
       </div>
   )
}
```

This demo is a bit extreme because each key press will trigger an state update. But its fine for this example.

What I want to know is how to handle this situation without re-rendering the "App" component each time. I was thinking of moving the state to the Input component itself, but if I did that I would not be able to assess all data from the `handleSave` function. Or at least I don't know how this can be accomplished.

Comment: you may try to keep track of non-empty items only (thus, decreasing the size of source array); you may try to decrease the number of updates, using `onBlur` instead of `onChange`

Comment: Taken at face value, moving the state elsewhere will prevent the App from rerendering, yes. You could also use pagination, or turn the inputs into uncontrolled ones.

Answer (score 0):

You are right by needing to have the state in App component, don't think you should avoid it.

You can use [react-window](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window)

which helps you with large lists (it does so by only rendering the items that are in or close to view)

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that whenever a component renders, every ancestor of that component also rerenders. For this reason keeping state (that you expect to change often) high up in the component tree is typically discouraged. You should try to hold any state as low down in your component tree as possible.

Some ways around this are to bring in a state management library like [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) which will allow you to have "global" state that doesn't cause the entire tree to rerender, or alternatively you can look into using `React.memo` on components that don't rely on that list state which will cause them to not rerender when the list changes.

In my own biased opinion, I think React devs tend to jump to using Redux far too quickly. I think applications that rely on redux are very hard to trace through and actually understand what is going on. Instead, I think something like this may work well:

```
const App = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(createItems());
  const handleChange = useCallback((value, index) => {
    const itemsCopy = [...items]
    itemsCopy[index] = value
    setItems(itemsCopy)
  }, [setItems]);

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <MyInput
            key={index}
            value={item}
            index={index}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        )
     })}
    </div>
  )
}

const MyInput = React.memo((props) => {
  return (
    <input
      value={props.value}
      onChange={e => props.onChange(e.target.value, props.index)}
    />
  )
})
```

Having the `React.memo` on `MyInput` will prevent each instance of the component from rerendering when one of the other items in the list updates, which is only really possible because of the `const handleChange = useCallback(...)`. By wrapping your handler in `useCallback` you are guarenteeing that the function is the literally the same function across renders, which allows the memoized components to not need to rerender since the handler is always the same function.